# Output at python shell is 'errors'

Tags: python, json, twitter

```
from rauth import OAuth1Service

twitter = OAuth1Service(
    name='twitter',
    consumer_key="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    consumer_secret="bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
    request_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
    access_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
    authorize_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize',
    base_url='https://api.twitter.com/1/')

request_token, request_token_secret = twitter.get_request_token()

authorize_url = twitter.get_authorize_url(request_token)

print 'Visit this URL in your browser: ' + authorize_url
pin = raw_input('Enter PIN from browser: ')

session = twitter.get_auth_session(request_token,
                               request_token_secret,
                               method='POST',
                               data={'oauth_verifier': pin})

params = {'screen_name': 'github',  
          'include_rts': 1,         
          'count': 10}              

r = session.get('statuses/user_timeline.json', params=params)
for i, tweet in enumerate(r.json(), 1):
    print tweet
    #handle = tweet['user']['screen_name'].encode('utf-8')
    #text = tweet['text'].encode('utf-8')
    #print '{0}. @{1} - {2}'.format(i, handle, text)
```

when i run this code.I got output at python shell is 'errors'. Any suggestions  help me out.If i treat 'tweet' as a dict i am getting typeerror

Comment: The correct API endpoint is `1.1` - what happens when you try that?